# angular4 Error as systemjs.config not found

Tags: systemjs, angular4-forms

Here im using angular4 in visualstudio2015 updated3  im getting Error as systemjs.config not found [image]

Masterpage Code

```
 <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="../../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="../../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="../systemjs.config"></script>

<script>
    System.config({
        "defaultJSExtensions": true
    });

    System.import('../Modules/startup').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your system.config.js , you need to have the configurations mapping done correctly, check if you have referred the .ts files right